# Can Main.js or vendor.js be used in figuring out the parameters needed for socket.io authentication of a website

Tags: socket.io

for a while now I've been trying to perform a socket.io client authentication.. what I need is the information showing in devtools... whenever I try, it closes immediately...just so you know the website doesn't have a public api yet... but when I checked their terms of services what I want to do isn't a violation so it's pretty much legal...
So I was thinking of what could actually be wrong.. like "is there a parameter or something I'm missing".. the question here is would anything in vendor.js or main.js help me find what I need for the authentication process to go through
This is the code I used back then.. (don't mind the tokens.. I had to change both)
[Vendor.js](https://quotex.io/trade-room/files/vendor.js?v=1660834993:formatted)

[Main.js](https://quotex.io/trade-room/files/main.js?v=1660834993:formatted)

```
import socketio
import json

sio = socketio.Client(ssl_verify=False,logger=True,engineio_logger=True)

@sio.event
def connect():
    print("Connected!")
    sio.emit('auth',{"token": "hshdjdjjdjdjdndhdhdhdhdhdysbsbdbdshd)
    sio.emit(json.dumps({"authorization":{"session":"gdioebrvrjdbdbdbendbdhd5LZ3NtB3h","isDemo":False}}))

@sio.event
def connect_error(data):
    print("The connection failed!\n\n" + data)

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print("Disconnected!")


@sio.on('*')
def catch_all(event,data):
    pass



@sio.on('handshake')
def on_message(data):
    print('Handshake',data)
    sio.emit("instruments/update",{"asset":"GBPUSD","period":60})
    sio.emit("indicator/list")
    sio.emit("drawing/load")
    sio.emit("pending/list")
    sio.emit("chart_notification/get")
    sio.emit("depth/follow","GBPUSD")
    sio.emit("tick")
    sio.emit("settings/store",{"chartId":"graph","settings":{"chartId":"graph","chartType":2,"currentExpirationTime":0,"isFastOption":False,"isFastAmountOption":False,"isIndicatorsMinimized":False,"isIndicatorsShowing":True,"isShortBetElement":False,"chartPeriod":4,"currentAsset":{"symbol":"GBPUSD"},"dealValue":1000,"dealPercentValue":1,"isVisible":True,"timePeriod":60,"gridOpacity":8,"isAutoScrolling":1,"isOneClickTrade":True,"upColor":"#0FAF59","downColor":"#FF6251"}})
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    sio.connect('https://ws.quotex.io/socket.io/', transports=['websocket'])
    sio.wait()
```